# How can I loop through SAS files and export to CSV?

Tags: csv, for-loop, sas

I'm not a SAS user but need to export *.sas7bdat datasets to CSV. I got how to do one like this:

```
libname M "/some_linux_path"; 

proc export data=M.SAS_file
    outfile="/home/different/path/new_file.csv"
    dbms=csv
    replace;
run;
```

Now I just need to do the same for a directory. I think I got the for loop but not clear how to specify the outfile name dynamically.

```
%let files = file1 file2 file3;

%macro loop(vlist);
%let nwords=%sysfunc(countw(&vlist));

%do i=1 %to &nwords;

%put &nwords;
proc export data=M.&nwords
    outfile="/home/different/path/new_file.csv"  what goes here??
    dbms=csv
    replace;

%end;
%mend;

%loop(&files);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your macro is using the right tool to COUNT the number of items in the list.  But you are not actually extracting the next item from the list.  That is what you would need to make the DATA= option correctly.  You could also just use the same value to help generate the OUTFILE= value.

First let's fix the macro:

```
%macro loop(vlist);
%local i name ;

%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&vlist));
  %let name=%scan(&vlist,&i);
proc export dbms=csv replace 
  data=M.&name
  outfile="/home/different/path/&name..csv" 
;
run;
%end;
%mend;
```

Now let's try running the macro.  No need to make a separate macro variable to call the macro

```
%loop(vlist= file1 file2 file3)
```

If you want to generate a CSV file for every dataset in the library you could just use a dataset to drive the looping instead of a macro:

```
proc contents data=m._all_ noprint out=variables; run;
filename code temp;
data _null_;
  set variables ;
  by memname ;
  if first.memname ;
  file code;
  put 'proc export dbms=csv replace '
      'data=' libname +(-1) '.' memname 
      "outfile='/home/different/path/" memname +(-1) ".csv'"
      ';run;'
  ;
run;
%include code / source2 ;
```